# Cannot register array of UICollectionViewCells

Tags: swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to register an array of UICollectionViewCells, but in the loop I get this error: ***cannot invoke 'register' with an argument lsit of type '(UICollectionViewCell, forCellWithResueidentifier: String)'***

```
My playground
***let cell1 = UICollectionViewCell()
let cell2 = UICollectionViewCell()
let cells = [cell1, cell2]
let collection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
for cell in cells {
    collection.register(cell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "hello")
}***

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to register once, not individual cells.

```
collection.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "hello")
```